# Go: Variadic function and too many arguments?

Tags: go, variadic-functions

Here's an example of the problem I'm having:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func foo(a int, b ...int) {
    fmt.Println(a,b)
}

func main() {
    a := 0
    aa := 1
    b := []int{2,3,4}
    foo(a, aa, b...)
}
```

When I run this I get the error `too many arguments in call to foo`. I guess I could understand why this is happening, but what's not clear to me is how I can get around it without having to make a copy of `b` with an extra slot at the beginning for `aa` (which I'd rather not do, as this code would be running quite often and with `b` being somewhat long).

So my question is: Am I just doing this wrong? And if not, what would be the most efficient way to do what I'm trying to do?

(Also, I can't change the signature of `foo`).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the Go runtime a variadic function is [implemented](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) as if it had an extra slice parameter at the end instead of a variadic parameter.

For example:

```
func Foo( a int, b ...int )
func FooImpl( a int, b []int )

c := 10
d := 20

//This call
Foo(5, c, d)

// is implemented like this
b := []int{c, d}
FooImpl(5, b)
```

In theory Go could handle the case where some of a variadic arguments are specified directly and the rest are expanded out of an array/slice. But, it would not be efficient.

```
//This call
Foo(5, c, b...)

// would be implemented like this.
v := append([]int{c},b...)
FooImpl(5, v)
```

You can see that Go would be creating a copy of `b` anyways. [The ethos of Go is to be as small as possible and yet still useful](http://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/06/less-is-exponentially-more.html). So small features like this get dropped. You may be able to argue for this syntactic sugar, as it can be implemented slightly more efficiently than straight forward approach of `append`.

Note that [expanding a slice with `...` does not create a copy of the underlying array](http://play.golang.org/p/20JJg3Mq8j) for use as the parameter. The parameter just aliases the variable. In other words it's really efficient.

Comment: The variable `b` looks like a slice rather than an array.

Comment: Good catch. It's too easy to break the rule "Thou shalt not call a slice an array!"

Comment: When expanding a slice, the slice struct is copied of course, but the underlying array is not copied. Just to be accurate.

Answer (score 12):

You can do something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func foo(a int, b ...int) {
    fmt.Println(a,b)
}

func main() {
    a := 0
    aa := 1
    b := []int{2,3,4}
    foo(a, append([]int{aa}, b...)...)
}
```

When expecting `b ...int`, you need to pass a `[]int...` or `int`'s as parameters. Don't can't mix `int` and `[]int...`